# Problems with C++ Templates & Polymorphism

Tags: c++, oop, templates, polymorphism, factory

I'm trying to create an interface that all of my factories will use (Currently I only have a factory for creating "Image" Classes (These are self made classes)). For my assignment I have to create and demonstrate a self made photo editing library.

```
    #include <string>
    #include "FreeImagePlus.h"
    #include <memory>
    #include "Image.h"
    #include "IMedia.h"

    #pragma once

    using namespace std;

     template<class T> class IFactory
     {
     public:
     IFactory() { }

        virtual ~IFactory() {}

    virtual T* Create(string filename) = 0;
    virtual void Initialize() = 0;


    };
```

This is the interface that my factories will implement. As you can see I've created a template which is what the factory will create and return.

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include "FreeImagePlus.h"
#include "IFactory.h"
#include "Image.h"
#include "IMedia.h"



#pragma comment (lib, "Libs/FreeImagePlusd.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Libs/FreeImaged.lib")

using namespace std;


class ImageFactory : public IFactory<IMedia>
{
public:
    inline ImageFactory();
    virtual ~ImageFactory();
    unique_ptr<fipImage> CreateImage(string fileName);

    virtual IMedia* Create(string fileName);
    virtual void Initialize();

};
```

Above is my factory that I'm trying to add the interface to. My knowledge of C++ is limited but I can't see where I'm going wrong. Whenever I call the library from my main (in another project that has included the library). Below is the .cpp of this

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ImageFactory.h"

using namespace std;

ImageFactory::ImageFactory() : IFactory()
{

}


 ImageFactory::~ImageFactory()
{
}

void ImageFactory::Initialize()
{

}


IMedia* ImageFactory::Create(string fileName)
{

    const char* file = fileName.c_str();
    Image* i = new Image();
    i->image->load(file);
        i->Initialise();
    if (!i->image->isValid())
    {
        throw exception("Image isn't valid. Please check the filepath and try again");
    }

    return i;
}
```

In the main function  I am calling(That is located on a separate project, but the project correctly includes the library and my previous attempts at this have been successful, but upon including the interface it has broken my code.. I know I'm doing something wrong):

```
     IFactory<IMedia>* im = new ImageFactory();
     IMedia* a = im->Create(filePath);
```

The factory will create and return an IMedia which I can use to draw an image. Upon running and crashing (It gave me a memory access violation, upon inspecting I came across this 0x001523dc {FipConsoleApp.exe!const ImageFactory::`vftable'} {0x0014109b {FipConsoleApp.exe!ImageFactory::`vector deleting destructor'(unsigned int)}, ...}). Anyway, The objective is to create a factory of type T (in this situation the concrete is of IMedia) that will create and return IMedia objects (More specifically I wanted to create an Image file so as you can see in ImageFactory.cpp I've cheated and just created and return an Image file, which is a child of IMedia. eventually I will flesh this out but I'm just trying to get something to work).

I understand that there may be many flaws in this code and that it's probably terrible. Please understand that I'm quite new to C++ as a whole so I'm trying to get my head around it, I'd appreciate any feedback and if anything is unclear I'll try my best to explain it. I'm just asking to see If anyone can notice any obvious errors with a possible explanation of what I'm doing wrong and what topics I should be studying further related to c++ :)

Comment: You should probably try in CodeReview instead. StackOverflow is for solving concrete errors.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I edited your question specifically to fit best practices on StackOverflow. Please do not just add back the fluff

Comment: Hi sorry, I reformatted my image prior to viewing these comments. My apologies if that had overwritten any of your changes!

Comment: Understood, I'll take it to CodeReview, appreciate the replies :)

Comment: What, no, do not take it to CodeReview. CodeReview is for working code only, which this apparently is not. Instead, provide *in the question* a [mcve].

Comment: Understood! My bad! Cheers for clearing that up

Comment: Use `std::unique_ptr` instead of owning raw pointers. You got a memory leak when throwing.

Comment: As mentioned already, you need to parse a lot of stuff out of this example, and also add stuff that is missing. For instance the definition of IMedia is absent and that is quite important.

Comment: I also don't understand fundamentally, why you need an interface for your factories. You are anyway hardcoding the type of the factory at compile time, so you do not need your factory to have an interface or use inheritance. Your factory can simply be a template. When you actually read a file to create something, dynamic polymorphism is justified because you may want the file to create different types based on its contents, satisfying the same interface.

Comment: By the way, you can omit the empty constructor in your interface, and you forgot to call `initialize` on `ImageFactory` in your main. Aside from that, there is no obvious bug in your code. Can your create a minimal example (in one file) that reproduce the error?